# What is targetId in getRetainingPath?

Tags: dart, garbage-collection

In the method [getRetainingPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vm_service/VmServiceInterface/getRetainingPath.html), what is targetId and how can I obtain it?

The object [HeapSnapshotObject](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vm_service/HeapSnapshotObject-class.html) does not have a field that looks as something that can be used as targetId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke [eval](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/blob/341ccdc74e39a31bb6a7ce37d2e3a2bf19e2a806/packages/devtools_app/lib/src/shared/eval_on_dart_library.dart#L129) for an expression that returns the object, the property `id` of the returned `InstanceRef` is the needed `targetId`.